# Sharing angularJS variable in an HTML file included in two different HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, include

In my application I've got different views which use the same piece of code. So, I put this piece of code in a file called *sharedFile*, all the variables and function have the same name, I checked twice.

This piece of code enables the display of a filter-box where the user can pick some filters, apply them and then the different filters applied are displayed. Everything works weel, HTTP request and so on, the only concern is that I have a "clear" button which enables to delete all the filters in one shot but actually when I click on it, filters are not in the URL anymore (that is what I want) but they are still displayed.

I share this file between 2 HTML files, and actually one works perfectly but the other one doesn't work only when the previous page visited was the first that works...

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks !

I put my code in case it can help :)

```
<!-- Enables the user to choose which filter he wants to be applied -->
<div  ng-show=" show.filterBox"  >
  <div>
    <strong>QUEUES</strong>
  </div>
  <span ng-repeat='queue in queues'>
    <button href="" class="btn btn-sm marginButton btn-default" ng-click="onAddQueueFilter(queue.id.toString())" ng-hide="routeParams.queue_id && isIdInRouteParams('queue_id',queue.id)">
      {{queue.name}}
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>
    </button>
    <button href="" class="btn btn-sm marginButton btn-primary text-muted" ng-click="onRemoveQueueFilter(queue.id.toString(), true)" ng-show="routeParams.queue_id && isIdInRouteParams('queue_id',queue.id)">
      {{queue.name}}
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </button>
  </span>




  <div>
    <strong>TICKET TYPES</strong>
  </div>
  <span ng-repeat='type in types'>
    <button href="" class="btn btn-sm marginButton btn-default" ng-click="onAddTypeFilter(type.id.toString())" ng-hide="routeParams.type_id && isIdInRouteParams('type_id',type.id)">
      {{type.name}}
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>
    </button>
    <button href="" class="btn btn-sm marginButton btn-primary text-muted" ng-click="onRemoveTypeFilter(type.id.toString(), true)" ng-show="routeParams.type_id && isIdInRouteParams('type_id',type.id)">
      {{type.name}}
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </button>
  </span>


    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-click="applyFilterBox()">Apply</button> - <a href='' ng-click='openCloseFilterBox()'>cancel</a>
    </div>
```

```
<div ng-show="!show.filterBox ">
  <div ng-show="routeParams.queue_id">
    <!-- indicate that the list is queue list when status and queue list are shown -->

    <span ng-show="routeParams.type_id" class="text-muted">queue:</span>
    <span class="label label-primary label-status-id small-margin-top" ng-repeat="queue in queues" ng-show="routeParams.queue_id && isIdInRouteParams('queue_id',queue.id)">
      {{queue.name}}
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
      style='font-size:0.7em; cursor:pointer'
      ng-click='onRemoveQueueFilter(queue.id.toString(), false)'/>
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="!routeParams.queue_id" class='small-margin-top'>
      -
      <a href="" ng-click="location.search('queue_id',null);">clear</a>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="routeParams.type_id">

   <span ng-show="routeParams.queue_id" class="text-muted">type:</span>
    <span class="label label-info label-status-id small-margin-top" ng-repeat="type in types" ng-show="routeParams.type_id && isIdInRouteParams('type_id',type.id)">
      {{type.name}}
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
      style='font-size:0.7em; cursor:pointer'
      ng-click='onRemoveTypeFilter(type.id.toString(), false)'/>
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="!routeParams.type_id" class='small-margin-top'>
      -
      <a href="" ng-click="location.search('type_id',null);">clear</a>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can You post Controller and app.js? Also fact that it works in one view, doesn't interfere that it should work in another view.

Comment: Please scale this down to a minimal representation of the problem and show how it is shared and where the specific conflicts occur with regard to controller and view

Comment: Hi,actually I just reset hard what i did, and just realized the probelm was already there even before I tried to implement new filters. Probably due to the way HTTP requests are done.. I'll try to figure it out, thank you for all your answers :)